# NSManagedObjectContext Category

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, anti-patterns

I am frequently setting up fetch requests in multiple classes to retrieve '`allRecipes`', or a '`lastModifiedDate`' from core data (plus a few other results).

It would be convenient to use a specialized category, `NSManagedObjectContext+RecipeAppConveniences`, for this. I don't really need to make this generic, I will just decide on a case by case basis if I am fetching the same thing frequently enough that it would be useful in the category.

Is this a standard practice? I haven't used categories much and just wanted to check it's not an anti-pattern, and that I'm not overlooking something that will cause me pain down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not going to be an anti-pattern, if you think that will make your code generic, readable you can go for it.

It was added to objective-c just for this flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple way is to add the method to a NSManagedObject subclass that takes the NSManagedObjectContext as a param, e.g.

```
@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject

+ (NSArray *)allRecipesInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;

@end
```

This pattern also aligns better with the new API for inserting new objects, e.g. `[Recipe.alloc initWithContext:moc]`.